# BCNF decomposition algorithm explanation

Tags: database, functional-dependencies, decomposition, bcnf

I looked in [Decomposing a relation into BCNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102485/decomposing-a-relation-into-bcnf) answers and tried it on my homework, but i don't get the correct answers, so  i ask for help in BCNF decomposition

Consider `R=(ABCDEG)` & `F={BG->CD, G->A, CD->AE, C->AG, A->D}`.
I start pick `A->D`.
Now i got `S=(AD), R'=(ABCEG).`
 I pick `G->A`.
Now i got `S=(AD,AG) R'=(BCEG)`.
 I pick `C->G`.
Now i think i need to get `S=(AD,AG,CG)` and `R'=(BCE)`, But the answer in the end is `(AD,AG,CGE,BC)` .what went wrong? or perhaps, a better algorithm?

Comment: Are the commas supposed to be there for (A,B,C,D,E,G)? it seems like you are working with (ABCDEG)

Comment: @Abundance i'll edit

Comment: Quoting from your linked answer: Where do you calculate the while test "S has a relation R' that is not in BCNF"? When you "Pick a FD: X->Y", where do you show that it "holds in R' and violates BCNF"? Are you *following* the algorithm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert a relation `R` and a set of functional dependencies(`FD's`) into `3NF` you can use ***Bernstein's Synthesis***. To apply Bernstein's Synthesis -

- **First** we make sure the given set of `FD's` is a **minimal cover**
- **Second** we take each `FD` and make it its own sub-schema.
- **Third** we try to combine those sub-schemas

***For example*** in your case:

R = {A,B,C,D,E,G}
FD's = {BG->CD,G->A,CD->AE,C->AG,A->D}

**First** we check whether the `FD's` is a minimal cover (*singleton right-hand side , no extraneous left-hand side attribute, no redundant FD*)

- *Singleton RHS:* So we can write our FD's as { BG->C, BG->D, G->A, CD->A, CD->E, C->A, C->G, A->D}.
- *No extraneous LHS attribute:* We can remove `D` from LHS of `CD->A` and `CD->E` since `D` is an extraneous attribute here (As we can get `D` from `C` *since C->A and A->D*). So we now have {BG->C, BG->D, G->A, C->A, C->E, C->G, A->D}
- *No redundant FD's:* We note that there are a lot of redundant dependencies here. Removing them we have {BG->C, G->A, C->E, C->G, A->D}

**Second** we make each `FD` its own sub-schema. So now we have -  (*the keys for each relation are in bold*)

R<sub>1</sub>={**B,G**,C}
R<sub>2</sub>={**G**,A}
R<sub>3</sub>={**C**,E}
R<sub>4</sub>={**C**,G}
R<sub>5</sub>={**A**,D}

**Third** we see if any of the sub-schemas can be combined. We see that **R<sub>3</sub>** and **R<sub>4</sub>** can be combined as they have the same key. So now we have -

S<sub>1</sub> = {B,G,C}
S<sub>2</sub> = {A,G}
S<sub>3</sub> = {C,E,G}
S<sub>4</sub> = {A,D}

This is in **3NF**. Now to check for **BCNF** we check if any of these relations (S<sub>1</sub>,S<sub>2</sub>,S<sub>3</sub>,S<sub>4</sub>) violate the conditions of **BCNF** (*i.e. for **every** functional dependency `X->Y` the left hand side (`X`) **has to be** a **superkey***) . In this case none of these violate **BCNF** and hence it is also decomposed to **BCNF**.

**Note** My final answer above is `(AD,AG,CGE,BCG)`. The solution you expect is `(AD,AG,CGE,BC)` but that's wrong. The last relation here (S<sub>1</sub>) should also have the `G` attribute as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Give input: A relation R0 with set (Minimal) of FD's S0.

Output : A decomposition of R into a collection of relations, all of which are in BCNF

Algo: 
      R <- R0, and S <- S0 
      Repeat till R is in BCNF.
          If there is a FD X -> Y that violates BCNF condition.
          Compute {X}+ , and choose {X}+ as one relation as R1, and
          another R2 as {(R - X + ) U X}
          Map FD set S on R1 and R2 (determine FDs on R1 and R2).
    Recursively repeat the algo on  R1 and R2.

Rule:
   1.Should be attribute preserving.
   2.Should be lossless
   3.Should be FD preserving

Example:
      R(xyz)  `FD xy -> z;   key : xy
                   z-> y;`

Solve:
      z-> y violet the  BCNF condition.

So decompose relation R
  `{z}+= yz;
   R1(yz) where key is z
  and  R2(xz) key is x`