# How to get rid of a into the key dependency?

Tags: functional-dependencies, data-management

Suppose we have a functional dependency from an attribute outside the primary key to an attribute inside the primary key. How can we get rid of this dependency (which I intuitively think it's bad)?

Particularly, suppose we have the following functional dependencies:

```
CS -> T
T  -> C
```

where `CS` is the primary key. In my example, it happens luckily that `TS` could also initially be the primary key, so the situation is converted to:

```
TS -> C
T  -> C
```

which is actually a situation where we don't have *into the key* dependencies anymore but we have a partial dependency, which can be solved easily by splitting our table into two tables as follows

```
| T | C |
```

and

```
| T | S |
```

but what if `TS` wasn't also a primary key? How could we get rid of the initial *into the key* dependency/anomaly?

Answer (score 1):

First, a note about the terminology: “primary key” is a term used for a relation
managed by
a Relational Database Management System, while in the normalization theory
the terms normally used are “superkeys” and “candidate key”, or simply “key”.

Second, in your example you are asking:

> How can we get rid of this dependency (which I intuitively think it's bad)?

The point is that the dependency is actually bad, in the sense that you have a relation with anomalies (in this case redundancy), but you *cannot* get rid of
this anomaly without having another anomaly, that is losing a functional dependency.

In fact you could transform the schema in BCNF, with the following decomposed
schemas:

R1 < (C T) ,
{ T → C } >

R2 < (S T) ,
{ } >

but, as you can see, the dependency CS → T is not preserved anymore, since no
subschema contains all the three attributes. And this is worse than having
a redundancy, because you could introduces inconsistencies in your database, that
is cases in which that dependency is violated.

In fact, this is a classical example in which the schema is already
in Third Normal Form (3NF), that, by definition, allow dependencies from a
set of attributes that are not a key, to an attribute which is part of a key
(called “prime” attribute).

So, this kind of anomaly is commonly accepted, and the relation is not decomposed.

Answer (score 0):

Any *"into the key"* dependency in a given relation R will be removed when decomposing the relation into Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF).

BCNF ensures that all dependencies are *"from the full key"*.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294136/bcnf-decomposition-algorithm-explanation/34350122) for how to decompose into BCNF form.

**Edit**

- *From the full key* : From the full primary key to outside the key.
- *Into key dependency* : From outside the key into the key.

And for completeness' sake, the other 2 type of dependencies - *Partial dependencies* are removed by decomposing to 2NF and *transitive dependencies* are removed by further decomposing it into 3NF. Hence by further decomposing into BCNF you essentially remove all the three types of dependencies ( *partial,transitive,into the key* )