# Is it possible to have a decomposed table to be the same as original one? BCNF Conversion

Tags: database-normalization, decomposition, bcnf

I have a relation R(A,C,D) where AC is the key and the FD set for the relation is F = {AC -> D, D -> C}.

I need to convert this 3NF relation to BCNF. However the result of decomposition is R(A,C,D) (exactly the same relation) and R(D,C), where AC and D are keys respectively.

Can a component relation of a decomposition be the same as the original relation?

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: [Decomposing a relation into BCNF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399094/3404097)

Comment: "decomposition" Well what is the definition of a decomposition to a higher NF? "the result of decomposition is" Please show your work, following what algorithm/process, per what presentation/textbook. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [ask] [Help] A NF decomposition to higher NFs always produces smaller components, or there's no point to it. (But if you followed an approved process, why do you care what you happen to notice?) PS Finding FDs, deriving FDs, definitions of BCNF, etc etc are faqs. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

If one of the components of a decomposition is the same as the original and the original is not in the desired NF (normal form) then the component is not in the NF & the decomposition isn't a decomposition to the desired NF.

If one of the components of a decomposition is the same as the original and the original was in the desired NF then you didn't need to decompose.

Proven algorithms for decompositions to higher NFs always return components that are smaller than the original or return just the original. Otherwise they wouldn't be useful since all they would have done is add relations when you already had just one.