# normalize table up to BCNF?

Tags: relational-database, database-normalization, bcnf

To normalize this table to BCNF I could split off one table R1(**ENo**, EName, ERoom, EPhone) but the rest of the attributes have a many-many relationship and I couldn't eliminate the dependencies.

> Attributes starting with E refer to employees, those starting with C refer to clubs, and those with P to projects. Employees, clubs and projects are each identified by their unique numbers. Names for employees are not generally unique. An employee is allocated with only one room and phone number; a room and a phone number can be shared by a few employees. A room may be associated with a few phone numbers, but a phone number is only mapped to a single room. Each club is characterised by its own size (i.e., the number of employees belonging to this club). Multiple clubs may be of the same size. Each project has an amount of funding associated with it. Multiple projects may be supported with the same amount of funding. An employee may be involved in different clubs and different projects. A club may have multiple employees as its members and a project may involve multiple employees.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nfgx.png)

I tried to convert to 2NF but couldn't get further than that employee table.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? What published textbook/reference are you following? What definitions? What algorithm/process? What are its steps? Where is the 1st place you are stuck? Why/how are you stuck? You essentially ask us to (re)write a textbook for an unidentified method & bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: [Decomposing a relation into BCNF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18399094/3404097)

Comment: "Each club is characterised by its own size (i.e., the number of employees belonging to this club). Multiple clubs may be of the same size." Those sentences contradict each other.